# python shap how to write feature_names from 3d array

Tags: python, shap

In my program,

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier,KerasRegressor
import shap

def CNN_pImportance():
    #1D convolutional neural network
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=64,kernel_size=2,padding='same',activation='relu',input_shape=(5,1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

    model.add(Conv1D(filters=128,kernel_size=2,padding='same',activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(64))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))

    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('linear'))

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
               optimizer='adam',
               metrics = ['mse','mae'])

    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
     my_model = CNN_pImportance()

     DE = shap.DeepExplainer(my_model,sc_cnn_tube_par_X_train_3D)
     shap_values = DE.shap_values(sc_cnn_tube_par_X_test_3D,check_additivity=False)
     shap.initjs()
     shap.summary_plot(
     shap_values[0],
     sc_cnn_tube_par_X_test_3D,
     feature_names = sc_cnn_tube_par_X_test_3D,
     max_display=50,
     plot_type = 'bar'
)
```

sc_cnn_tube_par_X_train_3D and sc_cnn_tube_par_X_test_3D are 3d array, but it errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 

C:/Users/win/PycharmProjects/allGlassStraightThroughTube/cnnTestNew.py", line 822, in <module>
plot_type = 'bar'
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\plots\_beeswarm.py", line 538, in summary_legacy
  max_display=max_display
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\plots\_beeswarm.py", line 641, in summary_legacy
  pl.scatter(shaps[nan_mask], pos + ys[nan_mask], color="#777777", vmin=vmin,
  IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

the sentence

```
feature_names = sc_cnn_tube_par_X_test_3D,
```

errors, could you please tell me how to write the "feature_names", how to choose feature_names from a 3d array

Comment: Are you sure the error is in line `feature_names = sc_cnn_tube_par_X_test_3D`? would you check line number?

Comment: plot_type = 'bar',error, but I feel the problem is at "feature_names = sc_cnn_tube_par_X_test_3D,",could you please help me to solve this problem